# wxWidget::wxWebView->Find wxWEBVIEW_FIND_HIGHLIGHT_RESULT Segmentation Fault

Tags: wxwidgets

wxWidget::wxWebView->Find - https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_web_view.html#ad85a7aa0351b6e6a6bffd4220f9758ee

Sample Code

```
wxWebView *webView;
webView = wxWebView::New(this, wxID_ANY);
webView->SetPage("<html><head><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no' /><meta content='en-us' http-equiv=\"Content-Language\" /><meta content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" /><title>Demo App</title><style type=\"text/css\">.auto-style8 {font-family: \"Bookman Old Style\";font-weight:bold;color:#734024;}.underline{color:#ff0000;}.text {color:#230fd2;}#wrapper1 {    width: 100% ; display: table;}#wrapper {width: 100% ; display: table;}#header1 {color: #E6F0F1;    display: table;    background-color: #0000ff;width: 100% ; text-align: center;height: 50px;font-size: 105% ; font-weight: bold;}#header2 {background-color: #B98264;display: table;    width: 100% ; height: 40px;text-align: center;color: #FFFFFF;    font-size: 75% ; font-weight: bold;}.auto-style13 {text-decoration: underline;}.text2{color:#000000;text-align: justify;}</style></head> <body style=\"color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF\"><div id=\"header2\"><p style=\"font-size: x-medium\" class=\"auto-style13\">Demo Page<br></p></div> <p class=\"auto-style8\" style=\"width: 100%;\">To Start  - <br/><br/>STEP 1. Select data</p></body></html>","");
long lMatchCount = webView->Find("a",wxWEBVIEW_FIND_HIGHLIGHT_RESULT  );
        if(lMatchCount == wxNOT_FOUND){
            wxMessageBox("Search not found");
        }else{
            //wxMessageBox("Search found" + lMatchCount);
            wxLogMessage("Matches: %s ",std::to_string(lMatchCount));
        }
```

Above code works correctly and returns number of occurrences of "a".

When webview->SetPage is updated again dynamically with large text ( any dummy content will do ) and if find call is called again **it crashes with Segmentation fault**

**If SetPage is loaded with large text in 1st instance itself it crashes as well so ruled out possibility of update causing the crash.**

Also tried loading large file from local file ( default.html contains above html code - replace any long string and it crashes with same result )

```
wxFile fFileIn("default.html", wxFile::read); 
wxFileInputStream in(fFileIn);
webView->SetPage(in,"");
fFileIn.Close();
```

Similar issue is reported here http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/15207

Comment: do you have a fix for that issue?

Comment: no.. looking for solution

Comment: can you try to debug it? What's the difference between running it the first time and when the page is updted?

Comment: aha.. i tried running with large text in 1st instance itself... it crashed with segmentation fault... without updating

Comment: are you handling `EVT_WEBVIEW_LOADED` event? Can you try `webView->SetPage(in,"");` i.e. with CallAfter to see if it still crashes?

Comment: @macroland yes, i have implemented wxEVT_WEBVIEW_LOADED, wxEVT_WEBVIEW_ERROR, wxEVT_WEBVIEW_NAVIGATED and other events. Also tried with SetPage(in,"") after EVT_WEBVIEW_LOADED, it still crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per discussion on this thread http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/15207.
We have workaround to this problem ( Still don't know why this is happening and what is the root cause )

1. Use the code mentioned in PR https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/pull/2626.
2. Call Find before the setPage

   wxFile fFileIn("default.html", wxFile::read);

   wxFileInputStream in(fFileIn);

   **webView->Find("");**

   webView->SetPage(in,"");

   fFileIn.Close();